# std::thread on OpenCV function generates error "Attempt to use a deleted function"

Tags: c++, opencv, stdthread

This is the code I'm using:

```
cv::Mat mask, foreground;
std::thread t(cv::threshold, mask, foreground, 254, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
t.join();
```

Compiling with Xcode 8 with support for C++11. Any ideas?

Here is the full error message:

> In file included from /Users/mlitvin/xcode/Create/ImageProcUtils.cpp:13:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:347:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function
>     __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get(__t))...);
>     ^
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:357:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__thread_execute' requested here
>     __thread_execute(*__p, _Index());
>     ^
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:369:42: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__thread_proxy >' requested here
>     int __ec = pthread_create(&__t_, 0, &__thread_proxy, __p.get());
>                                          ^
> /Users/mlitvin/xcode/Create/ImageProcUtils.cpp:71:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::thread::thread' requested here
>         std::thread t(cv::threshold, mask, foreground, 254, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
>                     ^
> In file included from :368:
> In file included from :3:
> In file included from /Users/mlitvin/xcode/Create/Create/Create_Prefix.h:25:
> In file included from /Users/mlitvin/xcode/Create/3rdParty/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp:50:
> In file included from /Users/mlitvin/xcode/Create/3rdParty/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56:
> In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:625:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:1087:5: note: '~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here
>     ~__nat() = delete;
>     ^
> 1 error generated.

**Edit 1:**

Looks like the problem is with passing an object of type `cv::OutputArray` as  argument.

Comment: What is the full error message?  It should tell you what function is deleted.

Comment: I notice you don't pass the address-of the member function into the thread ctor. I'd expect to see `&cv::threshold`. Perhaps it could be that the deleted function error message is a red herring and you just have a syntax error.

Comment: `threshold()` isn't a member function, it's not inside a class (`cv` is opencv namespace). I tried to add `&` before `cv::threshold` but the same error remains.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with passing an object of type `cv::OutputArray` as  argument.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by adding a proxy function in which only the output is passed by reference:

```
void cv_threshold(cv::Mat _src, cv::Mat& _dst, double thresh, double maxval, int type) {
    cv::threshold(_src, _dst, thresh, maxval, type);
}
...
cv::Mat mask, foreground;
std::thread t(cv_threshold, mask, std::ref(foreground), 254, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
t.join();
```

I'll be happy to know why the original method didn't work though - will accept an answer that explains that.